# loop wont switch around all fo the values in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Currently I'm trying to loop through an array in order to switch around the values based on other certain values. I understand there are probably better ways to sort or rearrange an array, but i'd like to do it this way just as a method of learning it.

This is my multidimensional array

```
 public static String[][] people = new String[][]
    {
    {
        "John", "blah", "120", "4"
    },
    {
        "Amy ", "blah", "99", "4"
    },
    {
        "Sophie", "blah", "100", "4"
    },
    {
        "Sarah", "blah", "98", "4"
    },
    {
        "Claire", "blah", "101", "4"
    },
    {
        "Rob", "blah", "105", "3"
    },
    {
        "Steve ", "blah", "85", "3"
    },
    {
        "Della", "blah", "102", "3"
    },
    {
        "Ron", "blah", "95", "3"
    },
    {
        "Bob", "blah", "102", "3"
    },
    };
```

and this is the method that should rearrange those records and put them into a String to display in the Dialog box

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String table = "";
        table = "<html><table'>";
        int ranking = 0;
        int m = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
        {

            if (i + 1 < people.length && people[i][3].equals(people[i + 1][3]))
            {
                if ((Double.parseDouble(people[i][2])) > (Double.parseDouble(people[i + 1][2])))
                {
                    String first1 = people[i][0];
                    String first2 = people[i][1];
                    String first3 = people[i][2];
                    String first4 = people[i][3];
                    String second1 = people[i + 1][0];
                    String second2 = people[i + 1][1];
                    String second3 = people[i + 1][2];
                    String second4 = people[i + 1][3];
                    System.out.println(first3);
                    System.out.println(second3);
                    System.out.println("time to switch lol");
                    people[i][0] = second1;
                    people[i][1] = second2;
                    people[i][2] = second3;
                    people[i][3] = second4;
                    people[i + 1][0] = first1;
                    people[i + 1][1] = first2;
                    people[i + 1][2] = first3;
                    people[i + 1][3] = first4;
                    // array[i][2] = temp2;
                    // array[m][2] = temp1;
                    System.out.println(i);
                    System.out.println(i + 1);
                  //  break;
                }
                m++;

            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < people.length; i++)
        {
            table += "<tr><td style=colspan='5'><center>" + ranking + "</center></td>";
            table += "<td style=colspan='5'><center>" + people[i][0] + "</center></td>";
            table += "<td style=colspan='5'><center>" + people[i][2] + "</center></td>";
            table += "<td style=colspan='5'><center>" + people[i][3] + "</center></td><tr>";
            ranking++;
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, table); //shows results in joptions pane
    }
}
```

The problem is that it doesnt switch the first and second record. it DOES switch the second and the third record, and then it does nothing else, why by all accounts and everything i can see, it should rearrange the first and the second, then the third and the fourth record, and finally the fourth and the fifth record.

When i add in a break, it works to switch the first and the second, and understandably doesnt do anything for the third and the fourth etc.

Can anyone see what the problem is here and why it isn't working, because i really dont see whats making it not work

Comment: What did you learn by stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: I ran your code and I ended up with amy,sophie,sarah,claire,john,steve,della,ron,Bob,Rob which looks like the correct order based on your data and code.  What order do you expect?

Comment: The order should have been Sarah, Amy, Sophie, Claire, john, Steve, Ron Bob, Della, Rob

I managed to get it working in the end using a boolean value and a while statement to continue looping through and swapping records as long as the value is true


By some miracle of god it works spot on